# Sum of Specific Convergent Series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let L be the sum of the following alternating convergent series $$L = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$
Now consider the rearrangement
$$1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{6}+... = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$
Show that it sums to $\frac{3L}{2}$.

We are given 2 extra hints:

1. the difference between $\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+3}+...+\frac{1}{4n-1}$ and $\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+4}+...+\frac{1}{4n}$ is small;
2. the sum $A(n) = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$ can be rewritten when considering the expression $A(n)-A(n-1)$.

I need help starting... what can I conclude from evaluating the hinted upon difference? And rewriting $A(n)$ leads to a recursion relation, with solution in the form of a harmonic partial sum, but again I can't see how it helps in any way. Thanks.

Comment: $$L=\ln(2)?{}{}$$

Comment: Indeed as it is the taylor series for ln, of course, but we haven't got into series of functions yet, and at this point it's supposed to be irrelevant I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the given relation by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ and add it to the original sequence. Now we get:

$$L = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac 13 - \frac 14 + \frac 15 - \frac 16 + \frac 17 - \frac 18 + ...$$
$$\frac 12 L = 0 + \frac 12 + 0 - \frac 14 + 0 + \frac 16 + 0 - \frac 18+ ...$$

---

$$\frac 32 L = 1 + 0 + \frac 13 - \frac 12 + \frac 15 + 0 + \frac 17 - \frac 14 +...$$
$$\frac 32 L = 1 + \frac 13 - \frac 12 + \frac 15 + \frac 17 - \frac 14 +... = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$

Additionally it's a well-known fact that $L = \ln(2)$. Also this kind of an rearragements are possible due to the fact that the series is conditionally convergent. Actually due to the [Riemann Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) we can rearrange any conditionally sequence in such a manner that it will converge to any giver number in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I feel as though you skipped the hints part.

Comment: @SimpleArt Doesn't that make my answer even better? After all I didn't need any hints. Just kidding. To be fair I don't really see how the hints are relevant to this problem, so I just wrote an answer I remembered from the past.

Comment: Me neither, they don't seem to be helpful all that much.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm uncomfortable with the transition from line 2 to 3: the sum of lines 1,2 is arranged in a specific way, and since the sum itself is arrangement-dependent, how can one justify this specific choice of order of summation of terms?

Comment: @yoni in the third line we are summing the first term of the first line with the first from the second and so on. Ex: $1+0 = 1; \frac 12 - \frac 12 = 0; \frac 13 + 0 = \frac 13; -\frac 14 - \frac 14 = \frac 12$. This is possible due to the fact that: $\sum [a_n + b_n] = \sum a_n + \sum b_n$ when both series are convergent.